# How to build Blender as a Python module?

Tags: python, compile

I have seen this question now many times and every question here and on other forum points to [build blender as python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) experimental tutorial by *[ideaman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42)*. Now sadly a lot of answers are invalid right now because this central link is down. I couldn't find anything by Googling so if anybody has a fork of the tutorial or a second source that would be great? The link can't be gone for too long, I saw an answer with it 4 months ago.

The only other thing I have found is [this tutorial for windows](https://cobertos.com/compiling-blender-as-a-python-module-for-windows-10-x64/), but it also references the now missing tutorial. Any ideas how to find it?

Comment: Are looking for all of blender as a python module or just "fake version" to be used for coding in an IDE?

Comment: I just want to insert cubes a camera and perform a visibility test. I was thinking of maybe ray casting not sure yet. But yeah not the full blender

Comment: The old wiki pages are still available with a slightly altered URL in blenders [archived wiki](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule). It really isn't that different to a normal blender build, mostly you need to enable the `WITH_PYTHON_MODULE` option.

Comment: I struggled with following the processes on the (archived) blender wiki, but managed to muddle through eventually with the help of this and a few other StackExchange questions. I've written up the full process I used on GitHub [here](https://github.com/BenRoullier/PyBlender/blob/master/installing_blender_for_python.md)

Answer (score 13):

Here it is pulled from the [archive.is](http://archive.is/hxSZ6) (all Ideasman42 cited):

## Overview

---

The official blender.org embeds a Python interpreter (CPython 3.x). This makes sense from the perspective of a user, who's primary needs are to have an application which can be extended with scripts.

However from the perspective of a Python developer, it can be useful to being Blender into your existing scripts and access its feature set.

The option to build Blender as a Python module is not officially supported, in the sense Blender.org isn't distributing it along with regular releases, Currently, its a build option you can enable, for your own use.

## Rationale

---

This is a build option to be able to import blender into python and access its modules

Possible uses include:

- rendering animations.
- image processing using Blender's compositor.
- video editing (using Blender's sequencer).
- importers, exporters (convert 3D file formats).
- development, accessing bpy from Python IDE's and debugging tools for example.
  automation.

This is mainly limited to features which can be usable in background mode, so you cant for instance do OpenGL preview renders.

## Prerequisites

---

**OSX**

get Python3.6-Framework from Python.org and install it.

## Building

---

Assuming you have a CMake out-of-source build setup, see: [http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake](https://archive.is/2MzVS)

Change these CMake options from the defaults:

```
WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
WITH_PLAYER=OFF
WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON
```

Everything should build as normal except in the cmake directory you will have `./bin/bpy.so` instead of `./bin/blender`

## Installation

---

**Linux**

- System Wide Install

  You may want install the module to the systems Python path, eg:

  ```
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  ```

  For a system wide installation:

  ```
  WITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=OFF
  ```

  note, `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` will be used as the target path, but this is auto detected, nevertheless, you may want to modify.

  Once these optiosn are set, run:

  ```
  make install
  ```
- Local Install

  Alternately you might want to use your user Python path (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)

  ```
  $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  ```

  For a local install use the following options:

  ```
  WITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=ON
  CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  ```

  Once these optiosn are set, run:

  ```
  make install
  ```

**Windows**

```
copy bin\bpy.pyd C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\
copy bin\*.dll C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\
del C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\python36.dll
xcopy /E bin\2.79 C:\Python36\
```

**OSX**

After compiling and "make install", copy needed files to your python framework

```
cp ./bin/bpy.so 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
cp -R ./bin/2.79 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Note. Unlike on *nix `C:\Python36\2.79` is not in the site packages, this is because of a difference in how Windows finds the scripts path and should eventually be fixed.

## Testing

---

This allows 'bpy' to be imported from python or other applications/IDE's which embed python, eg:

```
python -c "import bpy ; bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)"
```

This runs in background mode and has similar restrictions to running a script:

```
blender --background --python test.py
```

## Troubleshooting

---

The Python version requirements are the same with building a regular blender binary (if Blender us using Python3.6 then there is NO WAY to use another version - 2.7/3.2/3.6 will all fail).

On Windows, you probably won't want to use a debug build, since this requires a debug python installation (python36_d.dll rather then python36.dll), so while it can be made to work, its more trouble.

Comment: Does making such an install interfere if I would already have installed blender normally over apt? My idea is to install blender then test something and if it works to automate it, but I'm not sure if an already existing blender installation over ubuntus package manager would interfere with building it as a python module

Comment: @Hakaishin That shouldn't be a problem, you can install the builded module locally, there shouldn't be any interference

Comment: Do you know maybe if another version of python can be used like 3.6 or does it have to be 3.4? I vaguely remember reading somewhere that it will only work with 3.4 but I'm not sure

Comment: @Hakaishin It should be the same version as is bundled with Blender, so for 2.79b python 3.5.3. You get the version [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/where-can-i-find-what-version-of-python-is-bundled-with-certain-blender-versions)

Comment: Sry I was unclear, I meant if I have to compile it with a specific python version to make it work at all? I get that if I compile it with python 3.4 it will only work with 3.4 programs, but could I compile it with 3.6 and use it in a 3.6 program?

Comment: @Hakaishin Yes, this you can. You can compile Blender with python 3.6, pass `-DPYTHON_VERSION=3.6` when configuring CMake.

Answer (score 7):

I struggeld probably the same way as you did but i managed to actually build it as a Python module in the End.

I'm on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS System so the following report on how i achieved it might depend on the system.

Now to the process of the solution.

Starting point were the following three sources as follows :

1. [Your Question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module)
2. [An Archived Blender Wiki entry](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)
3. [The offical "Build from source" Wiki article](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu)

How did i achieve the build ?

I started by following the description provided of the 2. Source; which wasn't really precise in how to handle the source and so on and did not work for me in the end.

After a few failures of this, i went on by just following the 3. Source.

So i did what was stated there :

```
mkdir ~/blender-git
cd ~/blender-git
git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git
cd blender
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase origin master
```

Afterwards :

```
cd ~/blender-git
./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh
```

Now I had every bit of blender code and all dependencies installed. Since i did not want blender compiled with UI (as normal programm) i was curious what (described in the next step, step 3, in Source 3.) `make` in `~/blender-git/blender` offered.
So i proceeded with simply calling `make help` which gave the following (truncated for brevity) output :

```
Convenience targets provided for building blender, (multiple at once can be used)
* debug     - build a debug binary
* full      - enable all supported dependencies & options
* lite      - disable non essential features for a smaller binary and faster build
* headless  - build without an interface (renderfarm or server automation)
* cycles    - build Cycles standalone only, without Blender
* bpy       - build as a python module which can be loaded from python directly
* deps      - build library dependencies (intended only for platform maintainers)

* config    - run cmake configuration tool to set build options

Note, passing the argument 'BUILD_DIR=path' when calling make will override the
default build dir.
Note, passing the argument 'BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=args' lets you add cmake arguments.
```

"Oh Hey, look what we got!" There it was, a `make bpy` which promised to solve all my problems.

So i executed it and it compiled. But I ended up with the Python module in a, at least for my desires, wrong directory : `/usr/local/PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND`. I wondered how this happend.

I soon figured out that I had to reconfigure `cmake` in the new created `~/blender-git/linux_build_bpy` via `ccmake linux_build_bpy` while in `~/blender-git`. There i needed to enable the **Advanced Settings** via pressing `t` and then editing the Key `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` from `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND` to my desired Path `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

After changing this i had to rebuild the project, which didn't actually rebuild since the changed setting didn't affect the main build process.

Rebuild in `~/blender-git/blender` via `make bpy`.

In the End I also deleted the stuff in `/usr/local/PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND`.
(Ofc i could've just moved/copied it...)

That's how it worked form me. I hope this is helpful in any kind for anyone in the future.

**NOTES**:

1. `make bpy` might need superuser-rights so do a `sudo make bpy` and don't worry
   about a complete rebuild (it's allready done just linking/copying in the end needs 
   those rights).
2. The configuration after the first build might not be needed or can be done before
   hand, but i didn't figure out how to do so.
3. If followed through these steps, and the Python module (strangely a directory
   called 2.80 or simmilar number) exists in the desired path but yet you are not able to import the module `bpy` in any of your scripts, make sure that your desired path is included in your `PYTHONPATH` Env-variable.

Comment: I used `make bpy` as well but I specified the environment variable `PYTHON_ROOT_DIR` and let it point to the right python environment in anaconda (here called `bpy` as well): `PYTHON_ROOT_DIR="~/miniconda3/envs/bpy" make bpy`. This way, I have blender installed in the right folder directly.

Comment: I needed 'apt-get install libopenexr-dev' to get through the install_deps.sh

Answer (score 4):

As of 2.80 release there is a convenience make target.
As following [this](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) instruction, run `make bpy` in place of `make full` to automatically setup build parameters and compile Blender as a Python module.

Answer (score 3):

Since building libraries can be a bit cumbersome at times, I started by looking for pre-built options.

## Option 1 - PyR3

I found [precompiled libraries from PyR3](https://github.com/Argmaster/pyr3/releases) for Blender 2.93.5 and Python 3.9 for Linux (and then I installed it on Ubuntu 20.04).

```
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/_tmp/blender-precompiled
cd /home/ubuntu/_tmp/blender-precompiled 
wget -qO- https://github.com/Argmaster/pyr3/releases/download/bpy-binaries/bpy-2.93-linux64-py-3.9.tar.gz | tar xvz
sudo cp -r /home/ubuntu/_tmp/blender-precompiled/. /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

To test the installation

```
python -c "import bpy; bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)" # will only work with a display
python -c "import bpy; bpy.context.scene.render.engine='CYCLES'; bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)"
python -c "import bpy; bpy.context.scene.render.engine='CYCLES'; bpy.context.scene.cycles.device='GPU'; bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)"
```

Note: they also have instructions and install files for Windows. Post may be useful for those who have a compatible system.

## Option 2 - kitsune.one

I also tried installing via the conda channel of `kitsune.one`.

```
conda create --name blender3.2python3.10.5 python=3.10.5
conda activate blender3.2python3.10.5
conda install -c kitsune.one python-blender==3.2
```

Unfortunately they need Python 3.10 and also don't have cycles so you can't run the command

> bpy.context.scene.render.engine='CYCLES'

They only have ('BLENDER_EEVEE', 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH') which many folks online were not able work with while using `bpy`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `anaconda`, it is quite simple to build a `blender-python` package, which will allow you to `import bpy` in a Python script. The following (slightly modified) instructions were obtained from (https://launchpad.net/blender-conda).

If you want to build from source, execute the following commands:

```
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/blender-conda
cd blender-conda
conda-build .
conda install python-blender --use-local
```

If you want to download prebuilt packages, use

```
conda install -c kitsune.one python-blender
```

Note that I have no relation to `kitsune.one` and cannot verify the integrity of the prebuilt packages.

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python-blender

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/kitsune.one/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/kitsune.one/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
....

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to build full Blender to figure out it's target Python version. There's plenty places in Blender sources that point out to the supported Python version. For example, in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
  if(DEFINED PYTHON_VERSION AND "${PYTHON_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "3.7")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "At least Python 3.7 is required to build")
  endif()
```

As was already pointed out you can simply run `make bpy` to build Blender as a Python module. This command will automatically set all required variables, no need to worry about it. What is not set is `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` which can be set after `make bpy` was called for the first time.

By the way, it's important to follow the instructions and to have the directory structure exactly as described in the official [docs](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu#Automatic_Dependency_Installation):

```
your_blender_dev_dir/blender
your_blender_dev_dir/lib
```

(see the doc for more detail)

After calling `make bpy` another folder, with all the needed scripts and binaries will be generated alongside those other 2 folders. In my case, on Ubuntu it's:

```
your_blender_dev_dir/blender
your_blender_dev_dir/lib
your_blender_dev_dir/build_linux_bpy    - your new, generated folder.
```

During the first generation I also caught an exception in the very end of the process(related to `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` variable):

```
now run: "make install" to copy runtime files and scripts to PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND/2.90
[100%] Built target blender
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/python3.7/PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND/2.90/scripts
CMake Error at source/creator/cmake_install.cmake:45 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot make directory
  "/usr/lib/python3.7/PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND/2.90/scripts": No such
  file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:45 (include)
```

Now, this is where `ccmake` command comes in handy. It's basically just a frontend for `cmake` that helps you change its input parameters and other configs. Call it in the manner explained by Chgad, but also make sure you are following the hints at the bottom of `ccmake` console so that you properly configure`[c]` and generate`[g]` the corresponding `cmake` files. I missed one of the commands and as a result cmake files were not regenerated and cmake took variables from its cache on the next run.

In any case, if you managed to set `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` correctly to where you want it to be(I would recommend system-wide installation because copying all those files into all you virtual envs is a serious burden), you just run `make bpy` one more time and you are good to go.

Test it with something like:

```
$python3.7
>>>import bpy
>>>bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
>>>bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath='/tmp/my.blend')
```

Important note: CYCLES renderer is the only working option to run bpy for now, at least on Ubuntu. See [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/segmentation-fault-when-running-custom-built-bpy/11284/9).

Answer (score 2):

## Compiling blender as python module for Windows

[This guide](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) is completely fine, just follow the steps closely.
If you want to compile some specific release, just change branch in blender repo from master to eg. blender-v2.93-release and run make update to download appropiriate dependencies.

## Compiling blender as python module for Linux

### Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, with Blender v2.93 release and Python 3.9.5

##### Be aware that bpy.so will only work with python version that was intended to be used by coresponding blender binary, as explained [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) in the very bottom Troubleshooting section.

#### Install Packages

```bash
user@user_pc:~$ sudo apt update
user@user_pc:~$ sudo apt install build-essential git subversion cmake libx11-dev libxxf86vm-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libglew-dev
sudo apt install libwayland-dev wayland-protocols libegl-dev libxkbcommon-dev libdbus-1-dev linux-libc-dev
```

#### Download Sources & libraries

0. Move to some work folder, for us it will be ~/Documents. Create *blender-git* folder for source files and *lib* folder for dependencies.

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~$ cd Documents
   user@user_pc:~/Documents$ mkdir blender-git
   user@user_pc:~/Documents$ cd blender-git
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git$ mkdir lib
   ```

##### Following steps can be done concurrently, as they are independent and will take some time

1. **cd** into *blender-git* folder and clone blender repository

   **Edit, based on [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)s comment:**

   You can use `--depth=1` git flag to make downloading process faster, as it make clone 'shallow', see [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt).

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git$ git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git
   ```
2. *open new terminal window in `~/Documents/blender-git`* and **cd** into *lib* and download blender dependencies

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git$ cd lib
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git/lib$ svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-2.93-release/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64
   ```

##### After git finishes downloading

3. **cd** into newly cloned blender source repository and change current branch to v2.93 release branch

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git$ cd blender
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git/blender$ git checkout blender-v2.93-release
   ```

##### Wait unitl svn (point 5.) finishes downloading and close it's terminal window

4. Ensure You have right libraries and sources by running

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git/blender$ make update
   ```
5. Open `~/Documents/blender-git/blender/CMakeLists.txt` in your favorite text editor. Find and change following options:

   - `WITH_MEM_JEMALLOC` to **OFF**
   - `WITH_AUDASPACE` make sure its **ON**
   - `WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL` to **OFF**
   - `WITH_PYTHON_MODULE` to **ON**

   *then save and quit.*
6. run make

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git/blender$ sudo make
   ```

   it should build all libraries, and it's very likely to fail with following error:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a(pngerror.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stderr' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[3]: *** [source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/build.make:534: bin/bpy.so] Error 1
   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7272: source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/all] Error 2
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
   make: *** [GNUmakefile:345: all] Error 2
   ```

   if it does, it's **"fine"**, we expected it. If it didn't it's great, move to point n. to see how to install compiled blender. If different errors occurs, contact me, we will see whether I can help.
7. Now, error we encountered is caused by libpng.a not being compiled with -fPIC flag, its somewhat explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980606/static-link-libpng-into-a-shared-library). The solution is to compile it yourself, or use version compiled with -fPIC.
   8, To compile it yourself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980606/static-link-libpng-into-a-shared-library/69118170#69118170). For now we will assume that u have precompiled version, for example from [here](https://github.com/Argmaster/pyr3/releases/tag/bpy-binaries).
8. Download libpng.tar.gz, for example into `~Documents/libpng` folder
9. Open new terminal window in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and run

   ```bash
   user@user_pc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo mv libpng.a libpng_no_pic.a
   user@user_pc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo cp ~/Documents/libpng/lib/libpng.a libpng.a
   ```

   it will rename current libpng.a into libpng_no_pic.a and copy new libpng.a in its place.
10. Now we can again use our old terminal window form `~/Documents/blender-git/blender` and re-run make. It won't need to recompile all the dependencies, and should be pretty quick.

    ```bash
    user@user_pc:~/Documents/blender-git/blender$ sudo make
    ```

    If it succeeds, following file should exist: `~/Documents/blender-git/build_linux/bin/bpy.so` if it doesn't, it means that something has gone wrong.
11. Now copy **all** the files and `2.93` folder from `~/Documents/blender-git/buld_linux/bin` into *site-packages* folder of Your python installation.

##### This answer may get outdated after some time. You can check out [this repo](https://github.com/Argmaster/pyr3) where bpy.so is part of dependencies, so guides there are likely to be more up-to-date than this post.

Comment: Thankyou, very comprehensive. You don't recommend using `install_deps.sh` ?   Be tempted to mention a shallow clone option, as well as elaborating on python version, as may want this to use with a version other than default.

Comment: Well, honestly I just described how I managed to finally compile blender. I don't really care about which method is correct, because the methods described in numerous internet sources that I came across during the last 2 days, failed me. Also I edited the post do add note about python and blender version and precompiled libpng source. In the same link there are precompiled blender packages for linux and windows, but Im not so sure wheather they will work properly, so Im only mentioning it in this comment.

Comment: NP every bit of info helps   Was a regular builder, haven't for a while. It's a great feeling when it finally comes together. Recently UG'd to 20.04. tis very handy to have the real `bpy`  for editing scripts outside blender.. ,might get back to it.  Mentioned a  shallow git clone `--depth=1` as it saves a few gig of download.

Comment: I didn't understand this shallow clone part of your first comment, thanks for the deeper explanation, I have mentioned it, that's a helpful one ^^

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a "fake" version of blender's libraries so you can code bpy in an IDE with autocomplete, I'm currently using [THIS](https://github.com/mutantbob/pycharm-blender) open source library. It takes a running version of blender and strips out all of the data types and available functions.

Once downloaded it can be run with the following bash script with the paths changed to what they are on your local machine.

"PATH_TO_BLENDER\Blender.exe" -b -P "PATH_TO_PYTHONFILE\pypredef_gen.py"

The generated python files can be brought into your IDE and whereas they provide no functionality (The final script needs to be run in blender) you can code within your IDE of choice with autocomplete.

Comment: Good answer, but this is not my usecase I need to run the code outside of blender

Comment: Ah sorry. I miss-understood from the comments earlier.

Comment: No problem, maybe somebody else wants to do exactly this

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try:

```
pip install fake-bpy-module-<version>
#Then you can
import bpy
```

[fake bpy github link](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module)

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of troubles with installing bpy, until I figured out that you have to set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to /usr/lib/python3.7 and not to site-packages. Also in virtual environments, take the root folder of the venv and not site-packages.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the steps you've made? I'm not very familiar with make/cmake and not sure I'm passing BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX correctly.