# Editor and ways recommendation for Python addon development

Tags: python, add-on, text-editor

I am a Vim user and generally happy with it but I see some drags with Blender addon development when I use it. What editors and ways do you use to do your Blender development? Vim oriented solutions is prefered, but I am not against other ideas. The main thing I care is support for dark themes.

I also want proper Blender Api completion when using the editor. I will be mnostly on Windows.

thanks

Comment: Jacques Lucke started working on a VS Code extension just for blender development. An initial showcase is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbHN8w7GbJ0). You can install the extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development). It should work fine, but if it didn't, report the issue to the developer to get it fixed as it is still in testing.

Comment: thanks that looks great except that my dev desktop has no internet connection

Comment: Not sure I follow, if you can't download anything, then why are you asking for suggestion on the editor to use?

Comment: My desktop has no internet connection that would let an editor download extensions on demand. Naturally I can download Blender code, or an editor  etc and upload to my desktop. It seems like I need to fire a command to install that extension, whichs seems like Vscode needs active internet connection. I never used Vscode before.

Comment: The extension can be downloaded from the page I linked as a `.vsix`, which can then be installed manually in VS Code. Moreover, the extension will need three python modules, `ptvsd`, `flask`, and `requests`, which can be downloaded and then installed manually using pipe or `setup.py`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look into it. I apreciate that you made me aware of the new Vscode addon. I, naturally, love animation nodes, so trust the developer of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86221/discussion-between-yarun-can-and-omar-ahmad).

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches:

1. Use an auto-generate script to make stubs. The best one is probably [fake_bpy](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module), but that has shortcomings like missing `bpy.context`.
2. Compile as a python module. This gives accurate completion, but the compilation process is not well documented and I haven’t managed to get it to work consistently. Some instructions can be found [here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module)

The general state of tooling support for Python scripting right now is rather poor, so your best bet is to keep the API docs close at hand.