# Use a different Python interpreter

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to run Blender 2.80 with another install of Python 3.7 (the one coming with SageMath located on my computer in /opt/sage/local/bin/python3.7)

I followed the instruction of the page "[Tips and tricks](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions)", i.e.

- Removed the Blender Python sub-directory
- Run Blender, with the appropriate PYTHONPATH

Blender runs correctly. However when I print "sys.executable" I get

```
/Applications/blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
```

where I expected

```
/opt/sage/local/bin/python3.7
```

As a consequence the property "sys.prefix" is

```
/Users/brecht/dev/build_darwin/deps/Release/python
```

instead of

```
/opt/sage/local
```

It follows that I cannnot use some of the modules installed with SageMath, as they use external files whose locations is given starting from sys.prefix.

Is it the normal behavior, when removing the the Blender Python sub-directory ? If so is there a way to set up "sys.prefix" differently ?

Thank you very much for the help !!

Comment: One of the developers of Blender is called Brecht, maybe an example of his got hardcoded somewhere? Possibly user @brecht on this forum is the same person and can comment?

Comment: Some Blender documentation pages mention a way to build Blender as a Python module.
The [corresponding wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)
is now gone, but is preserved [in the Blender wiki archive](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule/) and [on the web archive's internet wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160514193543/https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule). Maybe worth a try?

Comment: Some people documented how they managed to build Blender as a Python module in [Blender Stack Exchange question 126959](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126959) and [Blender Stack Exchange question 117200](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200). I would try that, using SageMath's Python3 as the base Python installation.