# Resource for Blender-2.80 python-module for Linux

Tags: python, scripting, linux

While i successfully built the blender-2.80 python module on Windows (without changing anything), i have great difficulty building it for linux (at least in Ubuntu).

Is there anywhere where i can download a successful python module (make bpy) build of the current blender-2.80 for linux?

Comment: What part of the Blender compilation fails?https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reasons for this can apparently be very complex and i already tried many things. Therefore i wanted to ask here specifically if a resource exists where the blender2.80 python module can be downloaded, since i do not intend to change the blender source code.

Comment: Just for clarification you mean the `bpy` module? You can download and install blender, then it's located in `./2.80/scripts/modules/bpy` and `./2.80/scripts/modules/bpy_extras`. There isn't really anything to build, it's just python scripts. If you want to run a python script and use bpy, but for some reason don't want to call them through blender, you can call the python executable located in `./2.80/python/bin`

Comment: I need the bpy module (as in the result of a "make bpy" build) for running blender in a given python environment in linux. So using the blender executable or the blender internal python is not an option.

Comment: FWIW I build `bpy` as a python module on ubuntu 18, with no issues. Where is the hassle? Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126959/how-to-build-blender-as-python-module

Comment: Thank you batFINGER! I will try building again following those instructions. It is motivating for me to hear that it is possible building bpy in Ubuntu without issues :)

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for the comment, I misunderstood what OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: @batFINGER By following the instructions in the link i managed to successfully make bpy. (i think using sudo make bpy, following your comment there to modify site.py and using the ccmake function to get rid of the PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES-NOTFOUND made it work for me)... However i have not yet been able to get 'import bpy' working in the python shell... (bpy.so and the 2.80 folder are in my python3.7/site-packages)

Comment: Make sure the shell is started with `python3.7`  Comment was re keeping ubuntu system python3 as 3.6, or whatever it's up to,  or it stuffs up system upgrade scripts  (it doesn't take into account alternate versions links, ) among other hassles. Taking out python3 distpackages from apt installed 3.7 python's site.py  is a recommendation to keep installations separate. (_Recently had to do again after update_)  Worth noting if `pip3.7 install foo --user` is used for installing packages,  the module foo will be available to blender's python and system python 3.7.

Comment: It works now! Thank you!