# Do plugins/APIs exist to edit blender-python-scripts in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: python, scripting

I find the code editing environment on blender pretty stiff and it makes my development slower because I have to type every piece of code letter by letter so to say.
I was just wondering if it were possible to develop blender's scripts in `Intellij` before copying it down to blender's text-editor to run due to `Intellij-idea's` text-editor being better in terms of *code formatting and commenting*,  *auto-code completion and suggestion*,  *variable/method-or-function documentation*,  *column-selection-mode* e.t.c by installing a plugin or downloading an API in `Intellij`

Comment: I use vim. IMO Can break down getting autocomplete in vim into the same two suggested methods: a)  [building `bpy` as a python module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module), which completes as does any other python module, or b) run some script in blender  that creates a dictionary file that an autocomplete plugin uses.  Possibly finding part b) is better asked on an intellij site / forum.  Oh and could also mentions c) learning to touch type is often the quickest to resort to.

Comment: Why use IntelliJ when its devs made PyCharm specifically for python? Which also has some bpy integration possibilities if I remember correctly. But anyway, a lost of common IDEs have some way to use bpy, or the community has made their plugins for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use an external IDE to create your add-ons. Since an add-on is just a (bunch of) text file(s), it doesn't matter what you use to write them.

IntelliJ probably won't be able to find the `bpy` module, so expect some red squigglies.