# Blender as a Python Module Mac

Tags: python, command-line, compile

I've been following [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module?answertab=votes#tab-top) on how to build blender as a python module. I am current working on a Mac. I've successfully got the source from Git, but I'm stuck trying to edit the CMake parameters. The manual says the following:

[image]

The first thing I tried was running `cmake ../blender`, editing the `~/blender-git/build/CMakeCache.txt` file, and running `make` (first option). But I got the following error:

[image]

The second thing I tried was setting the parameters on the command line (last option), but when the `~/blender-git/build/CMakeCache.txt` file was generated, the options I had entered were not actually changed.

If I run `cmake` and `make` without changing any parameters, everything works perfectly. I must be doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to install the correct Python version first. Here it is very important that you have the exact python version (so 3.6 will not do if you need 3.7) installed that blender uses (see the python console inside blender to see the version it uses). The current python version for Blender 2.80-Beta is 3.7

Comment: This ccmake option method works for me: `cd ~/blender-git` then `sudo ccmake build` (at least if your build directory is called "build") then change the settings you want and don't forget to press c (for configure) and g (for generate) before quitting with q