# headless (or non-UI) mode for non-rendering purpose

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

Recently I am working on some projects that I want to control blender modeling outside blender.
Currently, I am able to do this with the UI version, and running on a computer with X-window, so the UI is totally fine.
Here is a simple description of what I am doing right now:
say I have a python process, randomly decide what action to take, e.g., move a vertex, do the subdivision, and so on, on an existing mesh.

The question is, I now have access to a server that does not have X-window, I am wondering how I can do the thing in background mode.
Since until so far, I am aware most of the headless mode is for rendering.
If I did not ask blender to render something, it just quit right after.
Following is the screenshot:
[image]

Is there any good approach that I can load the blend file, and then keep the blender up (not quit immediately), so that my script can send the follow up action to it?

thx a lot

Comment: Probably use Blender as Python module: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/117213/19156 and https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: thx for the quick response, I think blender as a python module is definitely one of the possible solution. But the worrying thing is that based my understanding, there will be no area, context and so on right?

Comment: as is also the case when running in bg mode.  _ie_ no UI elements eg area, region, does have context.

Comment: thx for the reply, do you guys know if Blender as Python module allow me access the context? E.g., do something like select_box in Blender 2.8? something like https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.select_box