# Use Blender Python Libraries Outside Blender

Tags: python

I'm writing a file import/export plug-in for Blender and would like to work a lot of the file-handling pieces in ipython outside of Blender. Is it possible to

```
import mathutils
```

without running inside of Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module?r=SearchResults&s=6|118.2311

Comment: Thanks, but that seems like a lot of work just to get a Vector3/RGB data type. Maybe I'll just roll my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mathutils available as pip module, use

`pip install mathutils`