# mathutils incorrect outputs in vscode

Tags: python, add-on, vector

I am using VSCode as external IDE for writing Blender scripts/add-on. I am getting incorrect results when I run python script in vscode for the following code:

```
import mathutils
my_vector = mathutils.Vector((1.0,1.0,1.0))
print("type: ", type(my_vector))
print("length: ", my_vector.length)
print("x: ", my_vector.x)
```

results:

```
type:  <class 'mathutils.Vector'>
length:  None
x:  None
```

The exact same script in blender text editor gives the correct result:

```
type:  <class 'Vector'>
length:  1.7320508075688772
x:  1.0
```

Both are using the same Python executable and sys.path.

my setup:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Python executable: /usr/lib/blender/2.91/python/bin/python3.7m
Installed Python, and Blender Development extensions on VSCode.
Installed debugpy and flask on python.

Comment: Hello, I'm voting to close this question since it is not related to Blender, but an external IDE. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi @Gorgious.. I wonder where we _should_ try to get help on using VSCode and its Blender extension. I keep running into (what I'm sure are are solvable) hitches myself.

Comment: @RobinBetts Fair point, and I'm all for it, there is very little documentation about it :) . But the question didn't mention they are using the Blender VScode extension so I assumed it was a regular python environment since `mathutils` can also be used in a standalone environment. That would explain why they behave differently. Maybe OP could add a little more information on how they setup the IDE and python environment. Either way, I feel like it's really hard to answer the question in this state

Comment: @Gorgious Ok, got you. A bit meta, this point..:)

Comment: @Gorgious Hi, I appreciate the response. I added some detail about my setup at the bottom. please let me know if I should provide more info.

Comment: @AlirezaBarkhordari So the first print outputs are inside the VScode terminal ? How did you install the mathutils module ?

Comment: @Gorgious, yes the first one is in vscode. I didn't install mathutils specifically for vscode. when I run `print(mathutils.__path__)` in vscode it returns this: 
 `/home/alireza/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mathutils`

Comment: Not using vscode so cannot clarify, but is the `mathutils` or the `bpy` for that matter the actual blender python module, or a fake module for intellisence autocomplete etc?  When running script from blender the `bpy` _et al_ paths are prepended.  What do you get for `mathutils.__path__` in blender?

Comment: Hi @batFINGER, you are exactly right, the mathutils that vscode is using is the fake one I had installed for intellisence (by this command: `/usr/lib/blender/2.91/python/bin/python3.7m -m pip install fake-bpy-module-2.91 --user`). Thanks for pointing out the problem. But now I dont know how to make it use the correct one because in the Blender python console, `mathutils.__path__` returns an error `AttributeError: module 'mathutils' has no attribute '__path__'`.

Comment: Error is as expected so nevermind that  message. (_was making point they are not the same,_)   Look for "build `bpy` as a python module"  There was also a recent post re `mathutils` being available as a stand alone module. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186553/use-blender-python-libraries-outside-blender/186554#186554