# Building Blender as Python Module based on Python 3.7?

Tags: python, compile

I am pretty new with blender, I am trying to build it as a python module, which I successfully managed to do following this link [blender-python](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).

However, this builds the module for python 3.9 but I want to to build it for python 3.7 since I want to incorporate other functionalities which use libraries in python 3.7.

After some research I found this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module) and tried that too but I am unable to achieve any success. I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this issue.

**Q:** How can I build blender as a python module based on Python 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a version of Blender that used Python 3.7 as its Python. This will also mean checking out a version of the SVN dependency repo for that version of blender (although I think checking out the tag from the git repo and running `make update` will do this for you).
From the other answer you mentioned:
"The Python version requirements are the same with building a regular blender binary (if Blender us using Python3.6 then there is NO WAY to use another version - 2.7/3.2/3.6 will all fail)."
I believe this article was written for Blender 2.8, so try doing
`git checkout blender-v2.80-release` and then `make update` and see if it'll build.

I := Python 3.9, because the walrus operator is awesome!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I'll take them into consideration and try building again. Reason for using Python3.7 is that, I want to use ML frameworks and some additional libraries which currently does not support future python3.9. However I agree with your suggestion on using python3.9.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have checked out the Blender 2.80 branch, However I am having trouble switching to correct svn branch as I cannot find the on that I need. Do you have any idea where I can find it?