# Is it possible to extract the bmesh python module and use it standalone, in other python projects?

Tags: python, bmesh

I have been searching around the web for python mesh processing libraries that can do "simple" mesh editing functions like edge beveling, or face extrusion. There's not really anything out there that I can find, that can do what blender does.

So I'm wondering, is it even feasible to build/compile/extract the bmesh system to work standalone?
I've been digging around in Blender's github, the amount of files related to bmesh is staggering..

Failing that, I'm also wondering if it would just make more sense to include a full blender install folder and simply append it to python path in the correct places and use the bmesh python module that way..

Not sure if bmesh requires blender to be up and running to function or not.

Comment: Probable duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module

Comment: if you build (or obtain) `bpy` as a python module, you can `import bmesh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not feasible in the sense you're thinking of.  Blender, including the bmesh implementation, is mostly written in C++. There isn't a bmesh python implementation, only a bmesh python interface to the C++ code.

You would have to extract the bmesh code, make it into a stand alone C++ module, and provide C++ runtime support in your python system.

Comment: thanks for your input!